# VS Code error when Attach to Visual Studio Code windows container on local machine

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-container

When I right click on a local Windows Docker container in Visual Studio Code > Attach Visual Studio Code, I get the following error. Can Visual Studio Code attach to a Windows container? If so, where can I supply the missing uname/passwd?

```
[2484 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[3364 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[3364 ms] Stdin closed!
[3371 ms] Shell server terminated (code: 126, signal: null)
container b125f4fce0c1de6ff89b6c94a27a7753a1c0c618d227c21f274e176edaedbdc6 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6FD489F4B: (caller: 00007FF6FD43E13A) Exception(12) tid(628) 8007052E The user name or password is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess] 
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"/bin/sh","User":"root","WorkingDirectory":"/","Environment":{"VSCODE_REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SESSION":"6ddd4179-d78f-4bdf-8723-35e92b8e49651614290826962"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
```

Comment: I hit the same `Stdin closed!` error when the VS Code tried to attach to a docker container that didn't have a CMD. It was just a base image, and so it would not stay open when vscode attached. I put a `while true; do sleep 1000; done` statement in the command and I got passed that Stdin closed issue. I am not sure if it would help in this case.

Comment: Do you have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this?

Comment: @AramBecker Start a Windows Container on Docker, try to connect to it from VS Code. Nothing else is needed

Comment: Hm. Okay, not sure I can help you with this, I'm running linux and can't pull the windows images

Answer (score 0):

Actually these are dev containers, there should not be authentication needed. usually that's a need in production. but see below article, on the location of JSON file where you can alternatively set credentials:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container

there is devcontainer.json where you can supply the username and password also you can specify.

Comment: Answers consisting of only links and very little context are discouraged. If you can, please expand your answer with more information or an example

Comment: added @AramBecker

Comment: I don't see any reference for password in the [devcontainer.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference). Also there is `containerUser` as well as `remoteUser`. It should be clear to users reading the answer what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on official documentation from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_remote-containers-limitations :

"Windows container images are **not** yet supported." So I believe this applies for attaching as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).